# How to get from CCA to PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, canonical-correlation

Saw this question in a applied scientist tech interview.

> How do you get to CCA objective function from PCA?

I really wouldnt know where to start with this.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202341 for some good ideas.

Comment: @whuber sorry but still hard for me