# Least square formulation of CCA

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, least-squares, canonical-correlation

I am trying to understand how CCA can be formulated as a least-squares
problem in the binary class case.

I understood how CCA and Least square problem works. But not getting how we can formulate a CCA to solve least square problem.

Comment: Well, it's been a while, but have you read "A Least Squares Formulation for Canonical Correlation Analysis" http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.149.4601&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: My answer to this question may be helpful to you.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309031/relationship-between-coupled-matrix-factorization-and-cca/309243#309243